# Entity Framework is not working in Cloud using MySql Server

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have done an application using MVC 4 with MySql database & Entity Framework(edmx). It is working fine in the local system but when deployed in cloud, I am getting the error when I am accessing the entity model. For example:

```
DinaEntities _entity = new DinaEntities();
var validuseridrow = _entity.users.FirstOrDefault
                     (f => f.UserId == userid && f.RecordStatus == 3);
```

While executing this kind of expression, I am getting the error as :

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

My web.config file code is

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DinaEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Dina.csdl|res://*/Models.Dina.ssdl|res://*/Models.Dina.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=root;password=*******;database=Dina&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
</entityFramework>
```

Please guide me how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the error is already stated in the question.

Comment: i am getting the error as:"Object reference not set to an instance of an object." I have already mentioned in my question

Comment: One of your variables is null: probably `_entity.users`. It would help to see the entire stack trace.

Comment: No, _entity.users is not null. Not only this while executing any of this type of query in _entity, Its showing that particular error.

Comment: @Srikant compile in debug mode and  get the stack trace. This will give you the exact line where something is null.